# How to convert from color to int automatically when using bindingsource?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding, ef-code-first

I have an entity that has a color property of type `int`. In my form, I have a custom dropdown (inherited from `ComboBox`) which displays a list of `KnownColor`.

This dropdown exposes a `ColorInfo` class which is just a class with 2 properties (Name: string, Color: Color). Furthermore I did the following:

```
   public new ColorInfo SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (ColorInfo)base.SelectedItem; }
        set { base.SelectedItem = value; }
    }

    public new string SelectedText
    {
        get
        {
            if (SelectedIndex >= 0)
                return SelectedItem.Name;

            return String.Empty;
        }
        set
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (((ColorInfo)Items[i]).Name == value)
                {
                    SelectedIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public new Color SelectedValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (SelectedIndex >= 0)
                return SelectedItem.Color;

            return Color.White;
        }
        set
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (((ColorInfo)Items[i]).Color == value)
                {
                    SelectedIndex = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using a `BindingSource` on my form and I bind this dropdown to my entity's `Color` property (which is int) by setting the `SelectedValue` property in the control's `DataBindings` section.

However, the property is always set to 0 even when I select a color. How can I automatically convert from color to int and back?

**UPDATE**

I've created this class:

```
public class ColorTypeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(int))
            return (Color.FromKnownColor((KnownColor)value).ToArgb());

        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is int)
            return Color.FromArgb((int)value);

        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

How and where do I use it so that the conversion takes place automatically?

Comment: Is your KnownColor a custom defined number that you intend to convert to colors or are you using any standards like ARGB ?

Comment: @ArmandoBracho It's the standard enum.

Comment: You have a Field or Property of type `int` bound to a Property of type `Color`. Is this what you want to convert? I think you should change the custom Combo `SelectedValue` property to `int` and make some conversions in its getter/setter. The getter should just return the `(int)KnownColor` of the `SelectedItem`, the setter should find the `Items` index corresponding to the `(KnownColor)value` (Linq `FindIndex` is quite fast, even though you'll have to first cast the `Items` collection `ToList()`).

Answer (score 0):

The [Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx) class has some methods that might help in your case, if you are using the [KnownColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor(v=vs.110).aspx) enumerator in your list then you can simply convert from that to color by calling the `FromKnownColor` method like this:  `var color = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.White);` you can also convert an integer to a color using the `FromArgb`method like this: `var color = Color.FromArgb(5);` and if you want to convert your color to an integer you can use the `ToArgb()` method like this: `var argb = Color.White.ToArgb();`

In your case to return a color from the selection on the list then your get should do something like:

```
public new Color SelectedValue
{
    get
    {
        //Asuming SelectedIndex is a valid int color value from your list
        if (SelectedIndex >= 0)
            return Color.FromArgb(SelectedIndex);

        return Color.White;
    }
```